# Azure mobile app and http get function

Tags: c#, azure, http, controller, azure-mobile-services

Very sorry if this is a simple question.

I have got get function, which simply returns a sting as it should, but if i want to send queries to the get function how would i do that on the server side? For example &name=ABC or &Car=Ford?

```html
namespace MobileAppAardra.Controllers
{
    [MobileAppController]
    public class HelloController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/Hello
        public string Get( int a)
        {
            if (a==1)
            {
                return "Jambo"; // "Hello from custom controller!";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Hello World DJ"; // "Hello from custom controller!";
            }
            //return "Hello World DJ"; // "Hello from custom controller!";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks You

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use simple class as model. For example define class

```
public class User {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
}
```

and then edit Your GET method to accept this class as parameter

```
public string Get( User user) {

    if (ModelState.IsValid && user != null) {

        // Do whatever You want with class

        String name = user.Name;
        String Car = user.Car;

    }
}
```

If You then make GET request using query parameters

```
?name=usersSuperName&car=bestCarEver
```

those parameters will be available in code above.

You can use same model class also on client which is usable when You want use MobileServiceClient.invokeApi(...) where one method overide accepts model.

Comment: Please mark it as an answer to close this thread, if it is solved